# Making a date from string 01JAN2021

Tags: r, sorting, date

I've been trying to sort this data below by most recent date for a person, and then only keeping the row with the most recent date.

```
df <- data.frame (Person  = c("Alex", "Alex", "Beth", "Beth"),
                  Date = c("01JAN2021", "15JUL2022", "31DEC2020", "15MAR2020"))
```

I ran the code below, but realized it was not sorting correctly because it was just reading the string straight in number then alphabetical order.

```
df_updated <- df %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  arrange(desc(Date)) %>%
  filter(row_number()==1)
```

When I realized this wasn't working, I tried looking up code to break the values by index in order to make Day, Month, and Year columns. I came across strsplit() and sub(), but couldn't get either to work. I also tried the as.POSIX* functions, but I couldn't find my type of date covered in the documentation. I figure once I can get this into a date format, that I can sort correctly and then group and filter for the most recent date.

Comment: `df$Date <- lubridate::dmy(df$Date)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `as.Date(x, format = "%d%B%Y")` for transform the character string into a date, then use `slice_max()` from `dplyr` package to get latest entry.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame (Person  = c("Alex", "Alex", "Beth", "Beth"),
                  Date = c("01JAN2021", "15JUL2022", "31DEC2020", "15MAR2020"))

df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%d%B%Y")

df_updated <- df %>%
  slice_max(order_by = Date, by = Person)
```

Result:

```
> df_updated
  Person       Date
1   Alex 2022-07-15
2   Beth 2020-12-31
```

Answer (score 1):

The `anydate()` function in in the `anytime` package does just that, and does not require you to specify a format as it will try a few 'reasonable' ones -- and 'DDMonYYYY' is one of these:

```
> df$parsedDate <- anytime::anydate(df$Date)     
> df                                             
  Person      Date parsedDate         
1   Alex 01JAN2021 2021-01-01         
2   Alex 15JUL2022 2022-07-15         
3   Beth 31DEC2020 2020-12-31         
4   Beth 15MAR2020 2020-03-15         
>
```

After that, you have a proper `Date` type and can to all the standard operations on it, including `max()`:

```
> max(df$parsedDate)  
[1] "2022-07-15"      
>
```

Which, together with standard base R aggregations, can give you grouped summaries:

```
> aggregate(parsedDate ~ Person, df, max)    
  Person parsedDate                          
1   Alex 2022-07-15                          
2   Beth 2020-12-31                          
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` package:

`parse_date_time` internally uses [`guess_formats`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/guess_formats.html):

```
df$Date <- lubridate::parse_date_time(df$Date, c("dmy"))
```

```
  Person       Date
1   Alex 2021-01-01
2   Alex 2022-07-15
3   Beth 2020-12-31
4   Beth 2020-03-15
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `aggregate`:

```r
> df$Date = as.Date(df$Date, format = "%d%B%Y")
> aggregate(list(Date = df$Date), list(Person = df$Person), max)
  Person       Date
1   Alex 2022-07-15
2   Beth 2020-12-31
```

As one-liner with conversion inside `aggregate`:

```r
aggregate(list(Date = as.Date(df$Date, format = "%d%B%Y")), list(Person = df$Person), max))
```